# Weak convergence $B\circ f_n\to B\circ f$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, weak-convergence

Let $B$ be a brownian motion and consider a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ defined on $[0,1]$, such that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for each $x$. Is it true that $B\circ f_n$ converges to $B\circ f$ as a process? I think this must hold but I do not find a direct way to prove it. I would appreciate any idea on this. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "convergence as a process"? Pointwise convergence, convergence in distribution,...?

Comment: @saz in distribution

Comment: I see... for stochastic processes there are different notions of "convergence in distribution", e.g. convergence in distribution on the space of the sample paths (here: continuous functions) or convergence in distribution of the finite dimensional distributions or...?

Comment: I mean convergence in distribution on the space of the sample paths

Comment: First, the weak convergence (in the sense of fdd) is clear: just compute the covariance and use the continuity of $f$. For the weak convergence you should use Prokhorov compactness criteria and  Garsia-Rodemich-Rumsey inequality (I think, you should additionally assume that function $f$ is Hoelder/Lipschitz continuous ).